# How to find optionset label when getdata from odata?

Tags: asp.net-ajax, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I want `Label of optionset` instead of value when entitydata retrieve using odata query in `ajax`.

```
var oDataUri = serverUrl + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/ProductSet";

$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   datatype: "json",
   url: oDataUri,
   async: false,
   beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
   },
   success: function (msg, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
        debugger;
        var data = msg.d;
        StateCode = data.StateCode.Value;
        ProductStructure = data.ProductStructure.Value;    
   },
   error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert();
   }
});
```

Can anybody suggest a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

OData queries do not return attribute metadata which holds the option set labels, just the option set values.

You will have to make an additional call to get the option set metadata and get the matching label for the option set value. Use [SDK.Metadata.js](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594428(v=crm.7).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer that is with the use of sdk I can get optionset label.

Answer (score 0):

I find one more way without using of sdk define below.

```
serverUrl = location.protocol + "//" + location.host;
var Query = "products";
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", serverUrl + "/api/data/v8.0/" + Query, false);
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 /* complete */ ) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status == 200) {
            data = JSON.parse(this.response);
            if (data != null) {

                alert(data.value[0]["statuscode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"]); //for optionset text

            }

        } 
        else {
            var error = JSON.parse(this.response).error;
            alert(error.message);
        }
    }
};
req.send();
```